# Thread 17: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x1) in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, exc-bad-access, lldb

This is my func where the crash is occurring:

```
//KabaSDKThunk.swift
 func isStarted() throws -> NSNumber {
        do {
            try sdk.isStarted() //Crash on this line
            print("thunk getIsStarted")
        } catch {
            print("thunk getIsStarted throws \(error)")
            throw error
        }
        return NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true)
    }
    
//KabaSynchronizationFSM.swift
 func handleStateSynchronizing() {
        if let kabaRegistered = kabaSDK?.isRegistered {
            if kabaRegistered {
                if let started = kabaSDK?.isStartedBool { //Line 118
                    if started {
                        registerSynchronizationDelegate()
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                   self.kabaSDK?.synchronizeWithBackend()
                                               }

                    } else {
                        send(.reinitializing)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                send(.syncFailed)
            }
        }
    }

extension IKabaSDK {
    var isStartedBool: Bool {
        ((try? isStarted()) != nil) //Line 193
}
```

This is the thread backtrace:

```
 thread #17, queue = 'KABA FSM - state machine204895', stop reason =
 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x1)
     frame #0: 0x0000000197ec2118 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 8
     frame #1: 0x000000010df30308
 HyattMobileKey`KabaSDKThunk.isStarted(self=0x000000028015d940) at
 KabaSDKThunk.swift:32:21
     frame #2: 0x000000010df30640 HyattMobileKey`@objc KabaSDKThunk.isStarted() at :0
     frame #3: 0x000000010dd341c8 HyattMobileKey`IKabaSDK.isStartedBool.getter(self=0x000000028015d940)
 at KabaSynchronizationFSM.swift:193:16
     frame #4: 0x000000010dd33fe0 HyattMobileKey`KabaSynchronizationFSM.handleStateSynchronizing(self=0x0000000283670bd0)
 at KabaSynchronizationFSM.swift:118:43
     frame #5: 0x000000010dd33db4 HyattMobileKey`closure #1 in KabaSynchronizationFSM.transitionDispatch(self=0x0000000283670bd0,
 state=synchronizing) at KabaSynchronizationFSM.swift:102:22
     frame #6: 0x000000010dc65df8 HyattMobileKey`thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () at :0
     frame #7: 0x0000000109bc0700 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
     frame #8: 0x0000000109bc1fc8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
     frame #9: 0x0000000109bc9150 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 684
     frame #10: 0x0000000109bc9ddc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 432
     frame #11: 0x0000000109bd563c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 852
     frame #12: 0x00000001dba14e10 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 284
```

How do I find out where the issue is?

Comment: The crashing frame is objc_retain - so the code is trying to bump the retain count on some object and since it is calling the objc version that's likely an ObjC object bridged to swift.  The access address is 0x1 so the object is probably nil.  That means it's likely you got an Optional<Something> bridged from ObjC and force unwrapped the object rather than checking that it was valid (e.g. with a `guard let`).  From the source snippet you posted, sdk is probably the bad object.